# Why matlab skips 2nd half of labels?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

Here is a pretty streightforward code for displaying matrix in scaled color using `imagesc` command. The problem is that final figure has wrong labeling and doesnt show 2nd half of labels(it should be from 1 to 21, but it is from 1 to 10)

```
figure;
imagesc(magic(21));
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21'})
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10' '11' '12' '13' '14' '15' '16' '17' '18' '19' '20' '21'})
```

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Matlab 2016b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign locations for those ticks, not just add labels.

```
figure;
imagesc(magic(21));
ax1 = gca;
ax1.YTick = 1:21;
ax1.XTick = 1:21;
ax1.XTickLabels = {'One','Two','Three',...
ax1.YTickLabels = {'Red','Brown','Green',...
```

Also since Matlab 2014b Mathworks created a new graphics system. You can access your graphics as objects directly instead of using `set` and `get` everywhere.

Comment: Good answer. now what if for labels, instead of numbers, I want to set a list of strings(for examples months) ?

Comment: @Woeitg you misunderstand. The `Xtick` tells you where to put the labels, `Xticklabels` say what is written in those labels. You need to use both.

Comment: @Woeitg nice ;) Accept the answer that helps you most ;)

Comment: @Woeitg it doest matter, just the one you like more. The important part is that you do accept one

Answer (score 7):

You set up the label text, but not the location, thus it will automatically put label locations and then substitute their text.

To set up the locations of the labels, first do:

```
set(gca,'XTick',...)
```

Then you can write in those labels whatever you preffer:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'banana', 'platano', 'potato',... })
```

Comment: @Woeitg I left it out specifically to make clear that your labels don't need to have the text of their location. You can put whatever in the `...`, e.g. `1:10:100`, but I assume in your case you need `1:21`

Answer (score 1):

You can test this:[image]

```
imagesc(magic(21));
set(gca,'XLim',[1 21])
set(gca,'XTick',[1:1:21])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21'})
set(gca,'YLim',[1 21])
set(gca,'YTick',[1:1:21])
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21'})
```

Comment: without xlim and ylim it also shows the same result

Comment: Yes, but if you do not use `XTick` then the `XLim` will be something like, `[0.5 21.5]`.

Comment: I see, there is a difference, however I prefer use it without Xlim and YLim. at least it looks better :-)